# Typo3: Custom order in tt_news

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I have used tt_news so set up a listing of staff members in a page, but now I realize that there is no intuitive mode to change the order in which the staff appears on the listing. It can be done changing the "date" field, but that concept might be a little weird to a redactor. Is it possible to have a custom order in a more easy manner, kinda like the "up" and "down" buttons of the content elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [extension for manual sorting of tt_news records](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ics_newssorting)

If it doesn't fit your needs try search the net using keywords: `typo3 tt_news manual sorting`

Comment: You save my day one more time, Marcus. Dziękuję!